# What do the splits look like in bivariate decision trees?

Tags: cart

Normally in multivariate decision trees, we can use all attributes in an internal node. Bivariate tree is a case where we are allowed to use any two attributes at an internal node. What do the splits look like in such a tree? How the splitting can be achieved?

Comment: Could you be more specific and expand on your question? Which tree algoritm for example? What do you mean with "bivariate" here?

Comment: I tried to clarify, hope you can help, thx!

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of that idea.

Comment: Splits in classification trees (which I assume you intend, since you tagged with `cart`) can be univariate or multivariate. Typically if you're in the situation of using both variables in a bivariate tree you'd split on a linear combination (linear function) of the two variables; you could then have subsequent splits either side of that split as you progress further toward the leaves.